# XQuery - How to select all parent elements where all child elements have a specific content?

Tags: xml, xquery

I have the following XML structure

```
<GAMES>
    <GAME>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <NAME>A Game</NAME>
        <ELEMENTS>
            <ELEMENT>
                <SOMEVALUE>true</SOMEVALUE>
            </ELEMENT>
            <ELEMENT>
                <SOMEVALUE>false</SOMEVALUE>
            </ELEMENT>
        </ELEMENTS>
    </GAME>
    <GAME>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <NAME>Another game</NAME>
        <ELEMENTS>
            <ELEMENT>
                <SOMEVALUE>true</SOMEVALUE>
            </ELEMENT>
            <ELEMENT>
                <SOMEVALUE>true</SOMEVALUE>
            </ELEMENT>
        </ELEMENTS>
    </GAME>
</GAMES>
```

I want to select all games which have every value `SOMEVALUE` on true. So in the example above I would like to get:

```
<GAME>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <NAME>Another game</NAME>
    <ELEMENTS>
        <ELEMENT>
            <SOMEVALUE>true</SOMEVALUE>
        </ELEMENT>
        <ELEMENT>
            <SOMEVALUE>true</SOMEVALUE>
        </ELEMENT>
    </ELEMENTS>
</GAME>
```

I tried it with this query, but with no success

```
let $db := db:open("game")/GAMES
let $games := $db/GAME[data(ELEMENTS/ELEMENT/SOMEVALUE) = 'true']
return $games
```

Any solutions? And also, is there a good source out there on which operations are possible with XQuery. All I found was not well documented or with no examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your verbal description "select all games which have every value SOMEVALUE on true" translates in my understanding into

```
/GAMES/GAME[every $value in ELEMENTS/ELEMENT/SOMEVALUE satisfies $value = 'true']
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kk

As for the documentation, read the specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/, https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
let $db := db:open("game")/GAMES
let $games := $db/GAME[ELEMENTS/ELEMENT/SOMEVALUE = 'true']
return $games
```

You do not need the data() function.

Comment: But that would select the first `GAME` as well as it has one `ELEMENTS/ELEMENT/SOMEVALUE` being `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're running the XQuery with but I expect one of these variations should do the trick:

```
let $games := $db/GAME[data(./ELEMENTS/ELEMENT/SOMEVALUE) = 'true']

let $games := $db/GAME[./ELEMENTS/ELEMENT/SOMEVALUE/string() = 'true']

let $games := $db/GAME[compare(./ELEMENTS/ELEMENT/SOMEVALUE/string(),'true') = 0]
```

I really value the [XQuery wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery) as a resource to learn XQuery for the first time.